# select row of minimum value without using rownum

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

I'm using `Oracle SQL` and i need some help with a query.

In the following query i'm selecting some rows with a simple condition (never mind hat kind of). From the output rows, i need to select the row with minimum value of DATE. For that, i'm using `ROWNUM`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
  SELECT NAME, DATE
  FROM LIST
  WHERE NAME = 'BLABLA'
  ORDER by DATE)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

However, **this query must fit to any other SQL languages**, and therefore i need to write this query without `ROWNUM`. 
Is there a simple way to write this query without using `ROWNUM`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, row limit syntax [differs between RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#Result_limits).

The following is portable between SqlServer, Oracle and PostGres:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT NAME, DATE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER by DATE) AS RowNum
  FROM LIST
  WHERE NAME = 'BLABLA'
) X
WHERE RowNum = 1;
```

However, other DB's syntax is different, e.g. MySql's `LIMIT`

Comment: Although the neatest, purest way would be to use Analytical Window Functions : http://www.orafaq.com/node/55

Answer (score 1):

```
    select * from LIST 
    where Date=(select min(date) from LIST where Name='BLABLA' )
    and Name='BLABLA'
```

Comment: Provided that there is exactly one row with that date :)

Comment: Yeah. **This query isn't correct**. The sub select "select min(date) from LIST" will give the minimum value from the whole table, but not from relevant selected rows.